# Symfony Doctrine LAZY Data loading

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I want to pass some data to **JavaScript** but i got empty vars like this

> var testsCompany = {};
>
> var testparams = "[{}]";

It is some issue related of lazy data loading in **doctrine**, i tried to change the **fetch** attribute value in **ManyToOne** association but in vain.

This is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var testsCompany = "{{ testsCompany|json_encode()|raw}}";
    var testparams = "{{ testparams|json_encode()|raw}}";
  </script>
```

This is my entity:

```
class TestParams
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Many testparams have One test.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tests", inversedBy="testparams",fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="test_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $test;


    /**
     * Many testparams have One param.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Params", inversedBy="testparams", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="param_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $param;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="required", type="boolean")
     */
    private $required;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->param = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return '*';
    }

}
```

and this is the controller code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/generate/{id}", name="prestashoptest_db_generate")
     */
    public function generateAction(Request $request)
    {
        $testId = $request->get('id');
        $testRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrestaShopTestBundle:Tests');
        $testParamsRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PrestaShopTestBundle:TestParams');
        $testParams = $testParamsRepo->findBy(array("test" => $testId));
        $testsCompany = $testRepo->find($testId);

        return $this->render('PrestaShopTestBundle:BOTest:generate.html.twig',
            array(
                "testsCompany" => $testsCompany,
                "testParams" => $testParams,
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: What about controller? It's the place where you fetch data and pass to view, so it may be helpful.

Comment: Ok, i will add the method code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have a solution:

1. I installed a **serializer**:

   composer require jms/serializer-bundle
2. configure it :

After you have installed the package, you just need to add the bundle to your AppKernel.php file:

`new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),`

3. and combine **twig** helpers:

> ```
>  <script type="text/javascript">
>  var testsCompany = {% autoescape %}{{ testsCompany|serialize|raw }}{% endautoescape %};
>  var testParams =  {% autoescape %}{{  testParams|serialize|raw }}{% endautoescape %};
>  </script>
> ```